# Классификация грамматических ошибок (задание № 7 ЕГЭ)

Tags: грамотная-речь, егэ

Имеется два предложения и два определения грамматических ошибок. Необходимо установить между ними соответствие.

Грамматические ошибки:
а) нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым;
б) неправильное употребление падежной формы существительного с предлогом.

Предложения:
1. Согласно правил современного этикета, при знакомстве мужчину представляют женщине.
2. Те, кто знал начальника отдела уже давно, не мог не заметить произошедших с ним изменений.

Мой ответ — а–2, б–1. По мнению составителей, верно: а–1, б–2. Какой вариант верен и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правильно указали варианты ответа.

Спогласно - предлог, управляет дательным падежом, поэтому ответ а: неправильное употребление падежной формы существительного с предлогом.

во втором предложении перед нами сложноподчиненное предложение, состоящее из 2 частей:

Основа в придаточной части: **кто знал (кто- ед.ч., знал ед.ч.)**,основа в главной части: **Те не мог(те - мн.ч., не мог - ед.ч.).** Связь между подлежащим и сказуемым нарушена, поэтому нужно поставить сказуемое «не **мог» во множественное число.**

Правильный вариант: **Те, кто знал начальника отдела уже давно, не могли не заметить произошедших с ним изменений.**

Хотя согласно Розенталю,  если в главном предложении соотносительное местоимение стоит во множественном числе **(те, все),** сказуемое при подлежащем **кто** в придаточном предложении может иметь форму как единственного, так и множественного числа.

Сегодня правильном считается только форма ед.ч. после подлежащего кто. Употребление мн.ч. после подлежащего **кто,** на ЕГЭ считается ошибкой.

Answer (score 2):

"Согласно правил". Здесь неправильное употребление падежной формы существительного (но почему **с предлогом**, не знаю). Корректно: "согласно правилам".

"Те... не мог". Здесь нарушение связи между подлежащим и сказуемым. Корректно: "те... не могли".

Comment: Согласно — предлог. То есть вы согласны с моим вариантом решения, верно?

Comment: Да, я согласен с вашим вариантом.

Comment: Тем более, что *согласно* — действительно предлог в данном  предложении.